# Find the number of items using only greater than query

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Can someone please suggest the algorithm for this problem?

There is a room full of candies (n where 0 < n < Infinity) and there is a gatekeeper for the room. Gatekeeper knows how many candies are there in the room. We have to find out how many candies are there in the room by asking a question to gatekeeper. The gatekeeper can answer only to a type of question in yes and no.
i.e.  Are the candies greater than a certain number?

```
If the candies are 110
e.g. 
1. Are the candies greater than 50? 
Answer: Yes
2. Are the candies greater than 112?
Answer: No
```

We can ask gatekeeper as many times as we want. Please suggest an approach which is less than o(n).

Comment: First, increment by powers of 2 or 10 or any other base (more than 10? more than 100? more than 1000?), then when you have the upper bound use binary search. Both stages are O(logn), for a total of O(logn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to find the upper bound. For this, you can try consecutive powers of 2 (or 10, or any other base, but for simplicity, let's say 2) until you find a number that's greater than the number of candles.

Now that you have your upper bound, you can use a basic [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) until you find the correct number.

For your example, 110, this could look like this:

- Stage 1: 2 -> x2 = 4 -> x2 = 8 -> x2 = 16 -> x2 = 32 -> x2 = 64 -> x2 = 128
- Stage 2: 128 -> -64 = 64 -> +32 = 96 -> +16 = 112 -> -8 = 104 -> +4 = 108 -> +2 = 110

It's easy to see that both stages will take *log<sub>2</sub> n* steps, for a total complexity of O(logn).

Comment: How does it solves with binary search? Can please give pseudo code?

Comment: @sabu The pseudo code is in the link.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a simple combination of exponential search and then the binary search. First, we find an upper bound for Number of candies by multiplying `Hi` by `2` until it's greater than the number of candies. Note that when we stop `Hi` is at most `2xcandies`. Therefore after we do the binary search the time complexity is `O(log(2n))` which is the same as `O(log n)`. Here is the pseudo code:

```
Hi = 1
while (are there more than Hi candies?==Yes)
    Hi = 2*Hi
Lo = 1,  
M = floor((Lo + Hi)/2)
while (Lo < Hi)
   if (are there more than M candies? == Yes)
       Lo = M+1
       M = floor((Hi+Lo)/2)
   else 
       Hi = M
       M = floor((Hi+Lo)/2)

return M
```

The answer is stored in `M` in the end. (in fact, by the end we have `Hi=Lo=M`. so either of them can be reported as the number of candies).

look up [exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) page on wiki.